# How to get url of private data in GCP

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I have stored some images in a bucket on GCP. I am using firestore to save some metadata about the image and some other information. I have an android application that would query the database to get results. The results include the image and the metadata associated with it. I was thinking of storing the URL of the images in the database, but I am unable to figure out how can I get the URL of the private objects in the bucket. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Cloud Storage for Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) to get a download URL for a file in the bucket, if you know its path.  This is discussed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files).

Comment: If I am getting it right, I should be storing file path in the database.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Or you can store the URL as well.

Comment: How can I get the URL of the object?

Comment: Using the instructions in the second link I provided. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url